How do I put PrivacyInfo.xcprivacy in third party libraries of Xamarin Forms project?
In an attempt to comply with the new PrivacyInfo requirements put in place by Apple, I added PrivacyInfo.xcprivacy to my MyProject.iOS folder.
But when I tried to publish the app, it got denied, because

"The PrivacyInfo.xcprivacy for the “System.Memory.dll” file contains “8FFB.1” as the value for a NSPrivacyAccessedAPITypeReasons." System.Memory.dll wasn't the only one. Several Nuget packages got called out like Xamarin.Forms.Platform.iOS.resources.dll and Microsoft.IdentityModel.Logging.dll to name a couple.

It also called out MyProject.dll. Do I also need to put the file in that project?
Here is the PrivacyInfo.xcprivacy I put in the MyProject.iOS folder:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
    <dict>
        <key>NSPrivacyTracking</key>
        <false/>
        <key>NSPrivacyTrackingDomains</key>
        <array/>
        <key>NSPrivacyCollectedDataTypes</key>
        <array/>
        <key>NSPrivacyAccessedAPITypes</key>
        <array>
            <dict>
                <key>NSPrivacyAccessedAPIType</key>
                <string>NSPrivacyAccessedAPICategoryFileTimestamp</string>
                <key>NSPrivacyAccessedAPITypeReasons</key>
                <array>
                    <string>C617.1</string>
                </array>
            </dict>
            <dict>
                <key>NSPrivacyAccessedAPIType</key>
                <string>NSPrivacyAccessedAPICategorySystemBootTime</string>
                <key>NSPrivacyAccessedAPITypeReasons</key>
                <array>
                    <string>8FFB.1</string>
                </array>
            </dict>
            <dict>
                <key>NSPrivacyAccessedAPIType</key>
                <string>NSPrivacyAccessedAPICategoryFileTimestamp</string>
                <key>NSPrivacyAccessedAPITypeReasons</key>
                <array>
                    <string>8FFB.1</string>
                </array>
            </dict>
            <dict>
                <key>NSPrivacyAccessedAPIType</key>
                <string>NSPrivacyAccessedAPICategoryDiskSpace</string>
                <key>NSPrivacyAccessedAPITypeReasons</key>
                <array>
                    <string>E174.1</string>
                </array>
            </dict>
            <dict>
                <key>NSPrivacyAccessedAPIType</key>
                <string>NSPrivacyAccessedAPICategoryUserDefaults</string>
                <key>NSPrivacyAccessedAPITypeReasons</key>
                <array>
                    <string>CA92.1</string>
                </array>
            </dict>
        </array>
    </dict>
</plist>


Here is the email I got from the AppStore:
Please correct the following issues and upload a new binary to App Store Connect.

ITMS-91055: Invalid API reason declaration - The PrivacyInfo.xcprivacy for the “ZXing.Net.Mobile.Forms.iOS.dll” file contains “8FFB.1” as the value for a NSPrivacyAccessedAPITypeReasons key instead of a valid reason code for using an API in the NSPrivacyAccessedAPICategoryFileTimestamp category. Values for NSPrivacyAccessedAPITypeReasons keys in any privacy manifest must be valid reason codes for the corresponding API category. For more details about this policy, including a list of required reason APIs and approved reasons for usage, visit: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/bundleresources/privacy_manifest_files/describing_use_of_required_reason_api. 

ITMS-91055: Invalid API reason declaration - The PrivacyInfo.xcprivacy for the “System.Memory.dll” file contains “8FFB.1” as the value for a NSPrivacyAccessedAPITypeReasons key instead of a valid reason code for using an API in the NSPrivacyAccessedAPICategoryFileTimestamp category. Values for NSPrivacyAccessedAPITypeReasons keys in any privacy manifest must be valid reason codes for the corresponding API category. For more details about this policy, including a list of required reason APIs and approved reasons for usage, visit: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/bundleresources/privacy_manifest_files/describing_use_of_required_reason_api. 

ITMS-91055: Invalid API reason declaration - The PrivacyInfo.xcprivacy for the “it/Xamarin.Forms.Platform.iOS.resources.dll” file contains “8FFB.1” as the value for a NSPrivacyAccessedAPITypeReasons key instead of a valid reason code for using an API in the NSPrivacyAccessedAPICategoryFileTimestamp category. Values for NSPrivacyAccessedAPITypeReasons keys in any privacy manifest must be valid reason codes for the corresponding API category. For more details about this policy, including a list of required reason APIs and approved reasons for usage, visit: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/bundleresources/privacy_manifest_files/describing_use_of_required_reason_api. 

ITMS-91055: Invalid API reason declaration - The PrivacyInfo.xcprivacy for the “Plugin.Permissions.aotdata.arm64” file contains “8FFB.1” as the value for a NSPrivacyAccessedAPITypeReasons key instead of a valid reason code for using an API in the NSPrivacyAccessedAPICategoryFileTimestamp category. Values for NSPrivacyAccessedAPITypeReasons keys in any privacy manifest must be valid reason codes for the corresponding API category. For more details about this policy, including a list of required reason APIs and approved reasons for usage, visit: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/bundleresources/privacy_manifest_files/describing_use_of_required_reason_api. 

ITMS-91055: Invalid API reason declaration - The PrivacyInfo.xcprivacy for the “Microsoft.IdentityModel.Logging.dll” file contains “8FFB.1” as the value for a NSPrivacyAccessedAPITypeReasons key instead of a valid reason code for using an API in the NSPrivacyAccessedAPICategoryFileTimestamp category. Values for NSPrivacyAccessedAPITypeReasons keys in any privacy manifest must be valid reason codes for the corresponding API category. For more details about this policy, including a list of required reason APIs and approved reasons for usage, visit: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/bundleresources/privacy_manifest_files/describing_use_of_required_reason_api. 

ITMS-91055: Invalid API reason declaration - The PrivacyInfo.xcprivacy for the “Telerik.XamarinForms.DataControls.dll” file contains “8FFB.1” as the value for a NSPrivacyAccessedAPITypeReasons key instead of a valid reason code for using an API in the NSPrivacyAccessedAPICategoryFileTimestamp category. Values for NSPrivacyAccessedAPITypeReasons keys in any privacy manifest must be valid reason codes for the corresponding API category. For more details about this policy, including a list of required reason APIs and approved reasons for usage, visit: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/bundleresources/privacy_manifest_files/describing_use_of_required_reason_api. 

ITMS-91055: Invalid API reason declaration - The PrivacyInfo.xcprivacy for the “IRA.dll” file contains “8FFB.1” as the value for a NSPrivacyAccessedAPITypeReasons key instead of a valid reason code for using an API in the NSPrivacyAccessedAPICategoryFileTimestamp category. Values for NSPrivacyAccessedAPITypeReasons keys in any privacy manifest must be valid reason codes for the corresponding API category. For more details about this policy, including a list of required reason APIs and approved reasons for usage, visit: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/bundleresources/privacy_manifest_files/describing_use_of_required_reason_api. 

ITMS-91055: Invalid API reason declaration - The PrivacyInfo.xcprivacy for the “hr/Xamarin.Forms.Platform.iOS.resources.dll” file contains “8FFB.1” as the value for a NSPrivacyAccessedAPITypeReasons key instead of a valid reason code for using an API in the NSPrivacyAccessedAPICategoryFileTimestamp category. Values for NSPrivacyAccessedAPITypeReasons keys in any privacy manifest must be valid reason codes for the corresponding API category. For more details about this policy, including a list of required reason APIs and approved reasons for usage, visit: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/bundleresources/privacy_manifest_files/describing_use_of_required_reason_api. 


There are tons more, but that gives the jest of what's going on.

Have you gone through this and made sure everything is correct https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/apple-privacy-manifest-support/
